# The term 'Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: powershell, azure

> The term 'Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile' is not recognized as the
>   name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
>   the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
>   path is correct and try again.

In visual studio its working fine but when I host the code on window server 2012 IIS then it giving above error.

c# code is

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{

    String SubscriptionFilePath = UtlityHelper.GetFilePath(Settings.Default.SubscriptionFile);

    PowerShellInstance.AddScript("Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile -PublishSettingsFile " + "" + SubscriptionFilePath + "");
   // PowerShellInstance.AddScript("Get-AzureSubscription | Out-String");

    var result = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();

    if (PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (ErrorRecord err in PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error)
        {
            string error = Convert.ToString(err.ErrorDetails) + " " + Convert.ToString(err.Exception.Message) + " " + Convert.ToString(err.Exception.InnerException);

            iLogger.PowerShellException(error);

        }
    }

    if (result.Count > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Import-Module` for the Azure commands?

Comment: I already used Import-Module command but still giving error-PS C:\Windows\system32> import-module  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement\Azure\A
zure.psd1"
PS C:\Windows\system32> import-module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ResourceManager\AzureResou
rceManager\AzureResourceManager.psd1"

Comment: Yes, I am having this same issue on a project I am working on.  Would love to know the answer.  Darn thing runs on-premise fine, but in an Azure environment on a Windows 2012 R2 server, we get this error.